# Changing cell style upon row.add execution

Tags: datatables, jquery-plugins

I have next code, which adds row to Datatable

```
  var rowed=$("#scores").DataTable().row.add([gameId,type,t,playerA,playerB,chooseA,chooseB,formatDate(t),winnerIs]).draw(false);
```

Suppose I want to have some style or class only for cell with this particular row added.. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

was able to figure out elegant answer, as supposed for my task.

```
$(rowed).find('td:nth-child(4)').addClass(colorA); // PlayerA color
```